# Barebox: USB cannot detect by "usb" command

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I have embedded system running Linux barebox. I can't detect the usb by command "usb". I have plugged in the usb storage but when i run "usb" it shows

> "USB: scanning bus for devices... 0 USB Device(s) found

What could be wrong with the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I checked with board supplier basically my version of barebox does not support usb.